# set_object_terms action hook based on the function in the published CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, terms, timestamp

I want to change the term in the custom taxonomy from the set of time intervals.
CPT = job, taxonomy = current-status, term = ongoing

The below code is not working and I don't know the missing code. Please help me!

```
<?php

add_action( 'set_object_terms', 'job_expiration' );

function job_expiration() {

    //Check the custom post type 'job'
    if ( is_singular( 'job' ) ) {

        //get the terms - category
        $categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'current-status' );

        //check the term 'ongoing'
        $term = term_exists( 'ongoing', 'current-status' );
        
        if ( $term !== 0 && $term !== null ) {
            
            //job expiration from the timestamp stored in db with key
            $expire_timestamp = 'int';
            $expire_timestamp = rwmb_meta( 'j_post_expire' );
            $current_time = time();
            
            // Ensure the timestamp parsed correctly.
        
            if ( $expire_timestamp ) {
                
                $seconds_between = ( (int)$expire_timestamp - (int)$current_time );
                
                if ( $seconds_between >= 0 ) {
                    
                    //change the post terms from 'ongoing' to 'expired'
                    wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID, array ( 368 ), 'current-status', true );
                    wp_remove_object_terms( $post->ID, array ( 367 ), 'current-status' );

                }
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure `is_singular` is appropriate here? `is_singular` checks the the current request is for a singular page of post type `job`. If the terms are being set in any other location, e.g. a page template, an AJAX request, REST API, post editor, then `is_singular` is `false` and your code does not run.

Comment: Also this hook provides the object/post ID as the first parameter, and a list of terms being set as the second parameters, but you have chosen not to use it or any of the other parameters, and are using `get_the_ID` instead, why? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/set_object_terms/ And how are you avoiding the infinite loop where setting the terms fires the hook again which sets the terms which fires the hook again which sets the ter...... etc?